# No such file or directory error trying to set command output to a variable

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash function which has the following lines of code

```
latest_build_change="$(p4 changes -s submitted ${PERFORCE_BASE}/$branch_name/build/... -m 10 | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f4)"
latest_src_change= "$(p4 changes -s submitted ${PERFORCE_BASE}/$branch_name/src/... -m 10 | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f4)"
```

when I run a script that calls that function, I get that error

```
script.sh: line 50: 2021/11/18: No such file or directory
```

2021/11/18 is the output of the second command set to latest_src_change, I am not sure what's wrong here and why doesn't the first command output that error too.

Comment: No space after `=`!

Comment: Oh, thanks that worked! I always get confused when it gets to spaces in shell scripts.